# Specific digit occurence counter for a given integer from 0 to given integer in Python

Tags: python

I want to write a function that counts a given number n's digits occurrence. I have the following code:

```
def count_number(n):
    c = 0
    for i in range(0,n):         # To parse from 0 to given number n
        for digit in str(n):     # To parse given n's digits
            if digit == '9':     # Let's say we want to count 9 occurrences
                c = c + 1        # 9 counter
    return c
```

Some expected outputs would be:

Given n - Return c:

n = 8 - c = 0 (0 nines in 8)// n = 100 - c = 20 (20 nines in 100) // n = 909 - c = 191 (191 nines in 909)

Instead most of my return are 0.

Please help.

Comment: You are close: change `for digit in str(n):` to `for digit in str(i):` so that you are looking for every number's digits till `n`, instead of always looking at fixed number `n`'s digits!

Comment: That works thank you very much. Another issue i found is the 1st for must change to `for i in range(0,n+1):` instead of just `n` in order to not miss a case.

Comment: Also this code works well for smaller n. If you seek for performance i would not suggest you to use my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've just made a tiny typo in the your code and fallen foul of for loops stopping before the final number.

Your loop looks like this:

```
for i in range(0,n):
```

But it should be like to account for the loop starting from 0 not 1:

```
for i in range(0,n+1):
```

In your code you are iterating on `n` not on `i` so you just need to switch this line:

```
 for digit in str(n):
```

to

```
 for digit in str(i):
```

So your final code should look like this:

```
def count_number(n):
    c = 0
    for i in range(0,n+1):         # To parse from 0 to given number n
        for digit in str(i):     # To parse given n's digits
            if digit == '9':     # Let's say we want to count 9 occurrences
                c = c + 1        # 9 counter
    return c

print(count_number(8))
#0
print(count_number(100))
#20
print(count_number(909))
#191
```

Comment: I saw the mistake on for simultaneously with your answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

It can be easily done with the "count" function

```
A=int(input())
s=""
for i in range(A):
    s=s+str(i)
print(s.count("9"))
```